# Performance goes bad for range based query on cassandra wide column family when implemented using multithreaded pycassa xget() calls?

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra, python-multithreading, pycassa, gil

I have a typical wide column family with {rowkey--> uuid4+date and timeseries data as columns}, on which I have implemented a range based query using pycassa xget() calls. Not that I was plagued with poor performance with single threaded code, I was more like curious to understand the difference in performance when the xget() calls are made in parallel rather than sequential (from inside of a for: loop).

I have used the "threading" python library to implement the multithreaded version of the range based query and performance actually degraded considerably. **Now I am aware of the effect that python GIL has on multithreaded code but is there any way I can be sure that this is infact caused by GIL? Can it be something else that is causing this ?**

Thanks in advance.

Note: I am not considering the "multiprocessing" library because I can't afford to have different ConnectionPool object for each sub-process.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I would try is playing around with different values for the `buffer_size` kwarg for `xget()` (the default is 1024).

If the GIL is the problem, you'll see CPU usage somewhere between ~90% and ~120% for the process.  Otherwise, you may want to adjust the size of the ConnectionPool to make sure there is at least one connection available for each thread.

If all else fails, try profiling your application: http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html.